# Outdoor kitchen cold water supply hookup and housing

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, outdoor, valve, pex

I need to hookup a recently installed outdoor kitchen faucet and two (total) hose bibs from an existing 1/2" galvanized pipe to the exterior.

In summary - 3 locations:

1. hose bib attached to home
2. line to faucet in kitchen
3. new bib on the other side of outdoor kitchen

I've already run conduit and pex underground (I know it can be direct burial) to the kitchen and the new hose bib location.

My plan is as follows:

Galvanized tee of the existing exterior house, run galvanized to hose bib and galvanized down to below ground level.  Then make the galvanized to pex connection running into a valve box.   At this point, insert a ball valve into another tee (pex connections). finish the two lines into new faucet and new hose bib.

Here are my questions:
Does this sound reasonable?
Is a regular irrigation valve box sufficient?
Anything I'm missing?

In case it's relevant, was just planning on using shark bite connectors on the pex.

Thanks for any insights.